# How Can I make a batch file a specific text file, and see if it matches information inside another specific text file?

Tags: batch-file

My software gives the user a special ID and places it in 2 text files. One for security and one for the user to observe. I'm trying to write a code that will compare the text inside those files, and make sure that they match. If they don't match, I want to send it to a screen alerting it that they don't match. 
Here's the test code I used to try to see if it would work (which it didn't)

```
@echo off
color a
cls
if "C:\Users\Cherida\Desktop\secured\KIRUKOTO MAINFRAME\secured\SAFETY VAULT\KID.txt" == "C:\Users\Cherida\Desktop\secured\KIRUKOTO MAINFRAME\secured\KID.txt" goto :gotcha
GOTO :fAIL
:gotcha
echo I WORK!
pause

:fAIL
echo I DON'T WORK!
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fc "filename1" "filename2" >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto fail
:succeed
```

should go to `fail` if the two files are not identical, otherwise to `succeed`

the `fc` command compares files and sets `errorlevel` to `0` if the files are identical, non-zero otherwise.

The `>nul` suppresses any messages that fc` might generate (eg. listing the differences)